# Streaming Parquet file in chunks for write operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, python-requests, parquet

I am taking beginner steps into DE and was tinkering with writing an ingestion script which does the following tasks:

1. Reads data from a source (in this case a remote parquet file)
2. Writes it to local for now, this can be changed to a remote location like s3 or other any database.

For this task I chose to use NY taxi data and trying to ingest data for a specific year which is configurable and in my attempt to read the data for 2023 year I discovered that it is quite huge after downloading it to local.

So I tried to optimize it by using response package and there is no native support for streaming in pandas, and *pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile* which supports reading parquet in chunks does not support URL. I have stored response stream & created byte object which I have passed in *io.BytesIO* to create a file like object which I can pass to the ParquetFile.

I am requesting the more experienced devs to take a look at my attempt and provide any suggestions to improve it. I personally feel that I could have somehow used the response object without needing the intermediate step of reading in Bytes.IO but was not able to achieve it. If any transformation step is required in future it would be best to do in chunks to be efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import io
from memory_profiler import profile

def fetch_NY_Data(year:int):

    #url to fetch NY Taxi data from https://www.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page, url is from inspecting the paruet file
    url =  f"https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/yellow_tripdata_{year}-01.parquet"
    
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True,verify = False) #verify = False to get around self signed certificate error, need to see how at self signed certificates to trusted certificates 
    chunks = []

    # Process the response content in chunks
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
        if chunk:
            chunks.append(chunk)

    #create a byte file from the chunks
    parquet_content = b"".join(chunks)
    #converting the byte file to a file like object
    parquet_buffer = io.BytesIO(parquet_content)

    #Direct reading of parquet file using read_parquet_file leads to high memory consumption as observed from docker-stats 
    #df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)

    #Set up the file pointer to Parquet object
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(parquet_buffer)
    batch_size = 1024 #Experiment for performance 
    batches = parquet_file.iter_batches(batch_size) #batches will be a generator
    file_name = None
    
    parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir,'data'))
    
    cnt= 0
    for batch in batches:
        #need to check if to_pandas is required
        df = batch.to_pandas()    
        #Construct the file name
        file_name = os.path.join(parent_dir, f"{year}_{cnt}.parquet") 
        try:
            write_file_to_path(df,file_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error writing: {e}")
            return e
        cnt = cnt+1

def write_file_to_path(df,filename):
        directory = os.path.dirname(filename)
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            try:
                os.makedirs(directory)
                print(f"Directory '{directory}' created.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occured while creating directory '{directory}'.")
        
        #TO remove any existing files in the parquet directory
        if os.path.exists(filename):
                os.system(f"rm -r {filename}")
        #Write data to the directory
        df.to_parquet(filename)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     fetch_NY_Data(2023)
```

Comment: This is a use case where resource constraints matter. With all due respect, I suggest you rephrase the code in terms of `polars` rather than `pandas`, since its design pays closer attention to such details from the get go. The ability to memory map a persisted parquet datastructure seems especially relevant. You're always free to export a DataFrame or a numpy ndarray at the end of it.

Comment: @J_H thank you for your feedback!! I have heard of polars but have not explored, could you expand on what you meant by "The ability to memory map a persisted parquet datastructure seems especially relevant" ?

Comment: The technique is illustrated [here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/polars-memory-pandas). Look for the "152MB" stat. 

If you map in a giant file but access only 1 MiB of it, then your RAM footprint is on the order of a meg. The in-core data layout is 1:1 identical with the binary file contents, on purpose. 
Also, polars is good at being lazy, at doing zero work when the described work is not actually needed. Half a century of relational databases has given us a large literature of query planning, and polars builds on top of that.

Comment: @J_H Thanks for the **polars** introductio, though it will be helpful in transformations but for moving around data one would still need to load the entire data into dataframe or read & write in chunks which I attempted.

Comment: Also looking for general feedback on the code to improve

Comment: I heard a complaint of "RAM is tight" due to dataset being large. So I offered the standard advice of "use a library that pays careful attention to RAM usage and zero-copy". Pandas has some nice qualities, but at first blush it doesn't appear to be the first tool one would choose from the tool box for this particular problem.